# SQLCLR-Publish fail for project using ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlclr

I have a sql clr that has a few functions and Stored procedures. I have the project in an `EXTERNAL_ACCESS` mode and a key for signing. - works just fine.

I have added another function to the project that uses the `ICSharpcode.SharpZipLib`. I initially got an incompatibility error for the versions, which I think I resolved following instructions on another post.

The project buids ok, but now I get the following error during that last phase of my project (SQL server db project). This is on my local machine, where I have admin privileges.

`Creating [ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib]...
(47,1): SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 6211, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 CREATE ASSEMBLY failed because type '<PrivateImplementationDetails>' in safe assembly 'ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib' has a static field '$$method0x6000014-1'. Attributes of static fields in safe assemblies must be marked  readonly in Visual C#, ReadOnly in Visual Basic, or initonly in Visual C++ and intermediate language.
(47,0): SQL72045: Script execution error.  The executed script:
CREATE ASSEMBLY [ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib]
    AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
    FROM 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
An error occurred while the batch was being executed.`

Appreciate any help !
Thx,
Satya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the first thing would be to see if you could do without `IcSharpcode.SharpZipLib`. If not then:

If you have access to the source for `IcSharpcode.SharpZipLib` you could change the static to be read-only.

Last option is to deploy the assemblies with `PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE`.

Comment: Thank you Niels and Solomon (for the concepts !). I ran into several issues, but was finally able to resolve it by setting the permission to unsafe. I will look at alternatives to SharpZiplib as Solomon suggested. I not have a clean publish. Appreciate your help !

Comment: @Satya As I mentioned, if you are using the `UNSAFE` option and hence the static variables are _not_ `readonly`, then you need to do a lot of testing to make sure you don't run into any race conditions. Testing from a single session will rarely expose any issues.

Comment: Thank you Solomon. Appreciate you letting me know. I also came across GZipstream that I can use. currently testing that, so I can avoid using the ICSharp library. I also stumbled across your series on CLR on SqlServerCentral, which I am reading. Great series. Love your presentation and detail.

Answer (score -1):

The CLR host that runs within SQL Server is highly restricted as compared to the CLR host running on the OS. One reason for the restrictions is that the App Domains are shared across sessions. So everyone executing a particular SQLCLR method (be it a Stored Procedure, Function, User-Defined Type, User-Defined Aggregate, or Trigger) is executing the same method in the same static class in the same App Domain. Hence, static class variables are shared resources, and unless you are very careful and deliberate in using them, they can quite easily lead to race conditions and odd (and difficult-to-debug) behavior.

The error message is about this, but it is also a bit misleading since it mentions that `SAFE` Assemblies do not allow such things. More accurately, it is non-`UNSAFE` Assemblies do not allow such things (i.e. neither `SAFE` nor `EXTERNAL_ACCESS`).

So, as Niels mentioned in his answer, you *can* mark the Assembly as `UNSAFE` and it will load and probably work. However, unless you know how that variable (and any others that are marked as static but were not yet mentioned) is used, it could lead to race conditions if one session overwrites the value that another session was still using. Or there is potential for a previous value to be left there that could adversely impact the next caller. You would need to look through the code to ensure that this isn't an issue prior to attempting to set the Assembly to `UNSAFE`.

While not as quick and easy, you really do need to start with updating the code to mark those static variables as readonly and try recompiling to make sure that there are no attempts to write to that variable throughout the code. And if other parts of the code do write to that static variable, then you need to refactor the code or find other code to do the same thing. I ran into this years ago and opted to use [DotNetZip](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=dotnetzip) for my [SQL#](https://SQLsharp.com/) project, though I still did need to make minor modifications for things such as static variables.